# React-Native Flatlist Load More with Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to load more data from firebase when page is scrolled down, But its not working properly. There are lots of docs about doing it on cloudstore but not on realtime db so im stuck.

Problems:

1. At the beginning it runs onendreached,
2. When it works, After 3-4 scroll bottom; its not calling onEndReached no more.
3. Sometimes onEndReach not working

my functions:

```js
retrieveNotifications = () => {
  var that = this
  database().ref('usernotifications/' + this.state.myuid).orderByChild('notificationDate').limitToLast(10).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val()) {
      that.setState({
        notifications: Object.values(snapshot.val())
      })
    } else {
      that.setState({
        notifications: null
      })
    }
  })
}

retrieveMoreNotifications = () => {
  console.log('retrieve more')
  this.setState({
    refreshingList: true
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    var that = this
    database().ref('usernotifications/' + this.state.myuid).orderByChild('notificationDate').limitToLast(this.state.notifications.length + 5).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.val()) {
        that.setState({
          notifications: Object.values(snapshot.val()),
          refreshingList: false
        })
      } else {
        that.setState({
          notifications: null
        })
      }
    })
  }, 1500);
}
```

And Flatlist:

```
<FlatList
  ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
  initialNumToRender = {1}
  onEndReachedThreshold = {0.1}
  onMomentumScrollBegin = {() => {this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false;}}
  onEndReached = {() => {
    if (!this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum) {
      this.retrieveMoreNotifications();    // LOAD MORE DATA
      this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
    }
  }}
  style={{flexGrow:0, marginBottom: 0, backgroundColor:'#fff'}}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  data={this.state.notifications.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(b.notificationDate) - new Date(a.notificationDate);
  })}

  renderItem={({ item }) => 
    <ListItem
      bottomDivider
      title={this.notificationTitleCreator(item)} 
      titleStyle={{fontSize: 15,}}
      rightSubtitle={ Platform.OS =='ios' ? 
      new Date(item.notificationDate).toLocaleString('tr-TR') :
      new Date(item.notificationDate).toLocaleDateString('tr-TR') + "\n" +
      new Date(item.notificationDate).toLocaleTimeString('tr-TR') }
      rightSubtitleStyle={{color:'#808080', fontSize: 16, marginTop: 5,}}
    />
  }
/>
```

So every scroll basicly i want to pull 5 more data from database than notification array length.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you put this code in expo snack and share with me the link I can fix it for you.

Comment: Do you know where is the problem ?

Comment: yes, I know where is the problem, I have spent too much time with this infinite scrolling stuff.

Comment: Well mate i dont know how to put it on expo snack as you want, can you tell me what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

onMomentumScrollBegin is deprecated and not working. Deleted it and edited thresh hold as 0.01 solved my problem

```
...

                          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
                          onEndReachedThreshold = {0.01}
                          onEndReached = {this.retrieveMoreNotifications}
                          style={{flexGrow:0, marginBottom: 0, backgroundColor:'#fff'}}
                          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

    ...
```